# How to implement Dispose to custom function in C#?

Tags: c#, dispose

I have the sample class as listed below an I need to open the db connection using CreateDataConnection() every time I call an API.

```
public class FlowerController : ApiController
    {
        DataConnection oDataConnection { get; set; }
        public void CreateDataConnection() 
        {
            ConnectionParameters oParams = new ConnectionParameters();

            oParams.strDatabaseName = "123123123123";
            oParams.strPassword = "123123123123";  
            oParams.strSchemaName = "123123123123";
            oParams.strServerIP = "192.168.1.1";
            oParams.strServerPort = "12313";
            oParams.strUsername = "123123123";
            oDataConnection = new DataConnection(oParams);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("api/flower/Activate")]
        public DBStatus Activate(W_Flower oFlower)
        {
            CreateDataConnection();
            DBStatus result = oDataConnection.Activate(oFlower);
            return result;
        }
}
```

I want to implement  Activate API as below

```
public DBStatus Activate(W_Flower oFlower)
{
   using (CreateDataConnection())
   {
       DBStatus result = oDataConnection.Activate(oFlower);
   }
   return result;
}
```

But this does not work as I do not have dispose method in CreateDataConnection. How can I implement dispose here? I have not done this method before.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including `CreateDataConnection`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `CreateDataConnection` to *return* the newly created connection,

```
public DataConnection CreateDataConnection() {
    ConnectionParameters oParams = new ConnectionParameters();

    oParams.strDatabaseName = "123123123123";
    oParams.strPassword = "123123123123";  
    oParams.strSchemaName = "123123123123";
    oParams.strServerIP = "192.168.1.1";
    oParams.strServerPort = "12313";
    oParams.strUsername = "123123123";
    return new DataConnection(oParams);
}
```

instead of storing it in a property.

Then you can do just

```
public DBStatus Activate(W_Flower oFlower) {
   using (var connection = CreateDataConnection()) {
       return connection.Activate(oFlower);
   }
}
```

Comment: This method still needs IDisposable.

Comment: @PCG You didn't say what `DataConnection` is, you just talked about not having `Dispose` method in `CreateDataConnection` (which is a method).

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
public class SomeClass : IDisposable
{
    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~SomeClass() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it following way :

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    bool disposed;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                //dispose managed resources
            }
        }
        //dispose unmanaged resources
        disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to implement IDisposable interface, after that, you can have Dispose method, just write your own logic in Dispose and that's all.